# Convert date time (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a column (datetime) in a Datagridview called DBO (date of birth) and it is converted with MM/dd/yyyy and I want to change it to this style (dd/MM/yyyy). I made this code and I get a error like " The conversion of the string " dd / mm / yyyy" for the ' Integer' type is not valid.

this is the sql string

myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorBasic SET " & _
        "DOB = convert(datetime, '" & Convert_Null(DGV1(9, 0).Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), #1/1/1900#) & "', 103) " & _
        "WHERE DoctorId = " & DGV1(0, 0).Value

DGV1 = datagriview 
convert_null is a sub that I created to not get a error when the field is null and I want to made some changes and save it.

I don't understand what is wrong.. and what is that integer type in the error.

Comment: You should think of setting DOB as a datetime in your database, it would save you a lot of trouble by using Parameters instead.

Comment: Trying to convert a `DateTime`'s format is the wrong approach, since a `DateTime` doesn't have a format. You would be better off creating a class that contains a `DateTime` and defining that class' `ToString()` method to `return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` instead.

Comment: but is datetime in database..

Comment: if it is DateTime in the database and DateTime in the DGV (*a column (datetime) in a Datagridview called DBO*) then you do not need to convert to string at all; just save it

Comment: but it shows the date on the datagridview as MM/dd/yyyy and I cannot change it to dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Perhaps just `Me.DGV1.Columns("DOB").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd\/MM\/yyyy"` before you display the form?

Comment: I think I did it, I changed to this (...)  "DOB = convert(datetime, '" & (DGV1(9, 0).Value.ToString) & "',103), " & _  and it accepted.

Comment: And that is not the best way.  Look at @GordThompson comment for the better way.